# Proper way to use HTMLParser.getpos()?

Tags: python-3.x, html-parsing

What's the proper way to make use of Python 3's [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html)'s  [getpos()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.getpos) method?

I used the following example to explore a subset of [html.parser](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html) methods:

https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#examples

My copy-and-pasted demo program works. But now I want to use the *html.parser*'s [getpos()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.getpos) method to acquire a tag's line number and offset.

After numerous experiments, including trying to add a separate *def getpos()* method to the class given in the example (nothing at all was output), the only way I've been able to make [getpos()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.getpos) return its line number and offset tuple is by inserting one line of (what seems to me to be) clumsy and ugly code per line 4 of the following snippet:

```
from html.parser import HTMLParser
...
class FlareTopicParser(HTMLParser):
    def handle_starttag(self, tag, attrs):
        # Following line inserted by me into class's examples.
        print("  Line, offset ==", HTMLParser.getpos(self))
        # This working code from examples per
        # https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#examples
        print("  Start tag:", tag)
        for attr in attrs:
        print("  attr:", attr)
```

That works -- to give but one example, for the zero-indented start tag on line 5 of the HTML input file it prints:

```
  Line, offset == (5, 0)
```

But the `HTMLParser.getpos(self)` construction in line 4 of the example code seems (to this only-occasional Python 3 coder) clumsy and wrong.

What's the correct, or if you will better, way to use [getpos()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/html.parser.html#html.parser.HTMLParser.getpos)?

Answer (score 2):

No need to override `getpos` in your parser; I suggest to rewrite line 4 as follows:

```
(line, column) = self.getpos()
print("line %d column %d") % (line, column)
```

With such call to `getpos()` you can also use `line` or `column` independently.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the way to use `getpos()`:

```py
row, col = parser.getpos()
html.splitlines()[row-1][col:col+100]
```